# Reemplazar cadena en archivo txt o plano con PHP

Tags: php, archivo

aquí nuevamente solicitando su ayuda y espero que me puedan ayudar a crear esta instrucción.

Quiero crear un script php que me lea un archivo plano y sustituya una cadena de caracteres, dicha cadena de caracteres está identificada con una expresión regular que he creado para ello.

Estoy utilizando preg_replace ya que me permite sustituir cadenas basadas en expresiones regulares. Si lo realizó desde el archivo php me funciona genial, el asunto es que es un lote de archivos, así que debo leerlos, buscar la expresión regular, sustituir dicha información, guardar el archivo y listo.

Lo más que he logrado hacer es lo siguiente, sé que me falta un toque pero no lo logró ver. Debo estar haciendo algo mal. El archivo plano de ejemplo va así:

> 29/11/18 11:07 a. m. - Noemi Venaim Corredora: Parral vendo amplio apto 160mts. 3hab mas servicio. 3baños. 2 ptos. Cocina empotrada. Edf joven con bellas áreas sociales. Vista panorámica. Planta electrica. Precio de oportunidad Ref 35.000 NEGOCIALES.
>   29/11/18 11:58 a. m. - Luisana Tavare Corredora: Luisana tavare vende casas terrenos en *la morocha* variedad de opciones con y sin piscina, mayor inf 04144301822

La expresión regular a buscar sería esta:

```
$patron = '/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}..............\-/m';
```

Que va tomar como valor:

```
$sustitucion = '|2018-11-29|';
```

Es decir, que se sustituye desde "29/11/18 11:58 a. m. -" por "|2018-11-29|"

Y el código completo sería éste:

```
$archivo = "prueba.txt";
$abrir = fopen('prueba.txt', 'r+');
$data = fread($abrir, filesize($archivo));

$patron = '/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}..............\-/m';
$sustitucion = '|2018-11-29|';
$datosnuevos = preg_replace($patron, $sustitucion, $data);
fwrite($abrir, $datosnuevos);
fclose($abrir);
```

El resultado que obtengo con éste código es el siguiente:

> 29/11/18 11:07 a. m. - Noemi Venaim Corredora: Parral vendo amplio
>   apto 160mts. 3hab mas servicio. 3baños. 2 ptos. Cocina empotrada. Edf
>   joven con bellas áreas sociales. Vista panorámica. Planta electrica.
>   Precio de oportunidad Ref 35.000 NEGOCIALES.
>   29/11/18 11:58 a. m. - Luisana Tavare Corredora: Luisana tavare vende casas terrenos en *la morocha* variedad de opciones con y sin piscina, mayor inf  04144301822|2018-11-29| Noemi Venaim Corredora: Parral vendo amplio apto 160mts. 3hab mas servicio. 3baños. 2 ptos. Cocina empotrada. Edf joven con bellas áreas sociales. Vista panorámica. Planta electrica. Precio de oportunidad Ref 35.000 NEGOCIALES. |2018-11-29| Luisana Tavare Corredora: Luisana tavare vende casas terrenos en *la morocha* variedad de opciones con y sin piscina, mayor inf 04144301822

Y lo que quiero es que me haga esto:

> |2018-11-29| Noemi Venaim Corredora: Parral vendo amplio apto 160mts. 3hab mas servicio. 3baños. 2 ptos. Cocina empotrada. Edf joven con bellas áreas sociales. Vista panorámica. Planta electrica. Precio de oportunidad Ref 35.000 NEGOCIALES.
>   |2018-11-29| Luisana Tavare Corredora: Luisana tavare vende casas terrenos en *la morocha* variedad de opciones con y sin piscina, mayor inf 04144301822

Alguien tiene idea ¿cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que abriste tu archivo con el modo 'r+' que significa leer y añadir, por lo tanto no borra el contenido original.

Prueba con este código

```
<?php
$archivo = "test.txt";
$leer = fopen($archivo, 'r+');
$data = fread($leer, filesize($archivo));
fclose($leer);

$patron = '/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}).+\-/m';
$sustitucion = '|20$3-$2-$1|';
$datosnuevos = preg_replace($patron, $sustitucion, $data);
echo $datosnuevos;
$escribir = fopen($archivo, 'w');
fwrite($escribir, $datosnuevos);
fclose($escribir);
?>
```

también puedes usar las funciones **file_get_contents()** y **file_put_contents()** 
que hacen la apertura-lectura-cierre y apertura-escritura-cierre ahorrándote unas cuantas líneas, quedando algo así:

```
<?php
$archivo = "test.txt";
$data = file_get_contents($archivo);

$patron = '/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}).+\-/m';
$sustitucion = '|20$3-$2-$1|';
$datosnuevos = preg_replace($patron, $sustitucion, $data);
echo $datosnuevos;
file_put_contents($archivo, $datosnuevos);
?>
```

También cambié tus strings de patrón y sustitución por uno que utiliza los mismos valores del dato original y no un texto arbitrario. En el manual de php te explica como funcionan las sustituciones http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php:

> replacement puede contener referencias de la forma \n o $n, siendo
>   preferida la última forma. Cada referencia de este tipo será
>   sustituida por el texto capturado por el n-simo patrón entre
>   paréntesis. n puede ser desde 0 a 99, y \0 o $0 se refiere al texto
>   coincidido por el patrón completo. Los paréntesis de apertura se
>   cuentan de izquierda a derecha (comenzando por 1) para obtener el
>   número de sub-patrones de captura. Se debe doblar la barra invertida
>   para poder usarla en la sustitución (cadena PHP "\\").

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar y estoy avisando que tal me va.

Comment: Excelente, funcionó a la perfección. Ahora necesito eliminar algunas líneas y estaría listo mi trabajo. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Finalmente modifique el patrón, porque tengo algunas líneas que contienen números de teléfonos que se separan con "-", por ejemplo, 0414-XXXXXX, entonces me eliminaba el 0414, entonces lo dejé asi: `$patron = '/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{2}).{13}/m';`